# Зачем переменной интерфейса присваивать ссылку на объект класса?

Tags: c#, объекты, интерфейс

Условно говоря, есть простенькая иерархия наследования, например интерфейс ISomeInterface, и от него наследующийся какой нибудь класс, например MyClass. Я могу сделать следующую запись при создании объекта:

```
ISomeInterface test = new MyClass();
```

Вопрос, зачем так делать? Какие плюшки я получу от подобного каста? Должна же быть какая то разница от например следующего способа создания объекта:

```
MyClass test = new MyClass();
```

Примеров в которых переменной интерфейса присваивается объект наследующего этот интерфейс класса я видел много (чаще всего это связано было с дженерик-коллекциями), однако только сейчас понял что не понимаю зачем мы строим код подобным образом.

Comment: интерфейсы не наследуют, а реализуют. а переменную объявляют классом или интерфейсом в зависимости от дальнейших задач, как удобно работать, так и объявляют. Способ создания объекта в обоих случаях у вас одинаков и находится справа от знака присваивания.

Comment: @0xdb и какие дальнейшие задачи передо мной должны стоять что бы я объявлял следующим образом? ISomeInterface test = new MyClass();

Comment: Одна из возможностей - это сделать коллекцию, которая будет содержать интерфейс (пример `List<ISomeInterface> TestList`), далее вы можете добавлять туда все классы, которые наследуются от данного интерфейса, что дает возможность сделать разный функционал (к примеру, вывести в WPF на экран пользователя список, где один объект будет показывать часы, другой таймер, третий секундомер).

Comment: Всю полезность приведения к общему типу Вы поймёте когда прикоснётесь к такой теме как паттерны проектирования. Если кратко, то приводя ссылку к интерфейсу, Вы инкапсулируете всё то, что выходит за рамки интерфейса

Comment: @teran Автор в комментарии выше имена перепутал.

Comment: @0xdb не понял про имена, но вам бы прочитать вот это: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/36/223826

Comment: @teran Второй комментарий сверху адресован Вам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно говорят, что так такой способ написания позволяет явно показать что вы не завязаны на конкретную реализацию интерфейса и можете ее в любой момент сменить... Не верьте. Нет никакого смысла менять в любой момент реализацию когда она вас и так устраивает.

В большинстве случаев правильным способом объявить переменную является тот, который дает меньше всего визуального мусора, то есть вот такой:

```
var test = new MyClass();
```

Тем не менее, существуют ситуации когда явное указание типа переменной важно.

**Во-первых**, возможна ситуация когда по какой-то причине нужные вам методы интерфейса имеют явную (explicit) реализацию в классе и не имеют публичных аналогов. В таком случае другого варианта кроме как использовать интерфейс у вас и нет:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    void Foo();
}
class MyClass : ISomeInterface {
    void ISomeInterface.Foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}

ISomeInterface test = new MyClass();
test.Foo();

MyClass test2 = new MyClass();
test2.Foo(); // ошибка компиляции: метод не найден
```

**Во-вторых**, возможна ситуация когда у класса есть несколько интерфейсов, а у какого-то метода - несколько перегрузок. В таком случае без явного указания интерфейса компилятор не сможет выбрать нужную перегрузку:

```
void Foo(ICollection<int> arg) {}
void Foo(IReadOnlyCollection<int> arg) {}

ICollection<int> test = new List<int>();
Foo(test);

var test2 = new List<int>();
Foo(test2); // ошибка компиляции: найдено несколько методов
```

**В-третьих**, иногда требуется потом присвоить переменной что-то другое:

```
ISomeInterface test = new MyClass();
if (...)
    test = new MyOtherClass(); // тут могла бы быть ошибка компиляции
```

**В-четвертых**, при использовании нисходящего программирования можно попросить IDE создавать заглушки еще несуществующих методов. В таком случае IDE определяет тип параметра исходя из типа переменной:

```
ISomeInterface test = new MyClass();
Foo(test);

void Foo(ISomeInterface test) // метод сгенерирован IDE
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

MyClass test = new MyClass();
Foo(test);

void Foo(MyClass test) // метод сгенерирован IDE
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Ну а в качестве параметров методов, конечно же, нужно использовать интерфейсы (ведь для чего-то же интерфейс ISomeInterface придумывался?)